# Not able to add breakpoint in karate feature file using VS Code and Karate Runner extension

Tags: karate

We are using VS Code version 1.53.2 and Karate Runner version 1.0.8
karate version 1.3.0

In a feature file we are not able to  add remove breakpoints. We can debug the tests using karate jar.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "karate",
            "name": "Karate (debug): Standalone",
            "request": "launch",
            "feature": "${command:karateRunner.getDebugFile}",
            "karateOptions": "",
            "karateCli": "${config:karateRunner.karateJar.commandLineArgs} -d"
        }
    ]
}
```

We have tried changing the default shell to cmd but no luck. In java files debug points can be added but not in feature files.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: just FYI - the official Karate Labs extension is this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=karatelabs.karate - and debug is a paid upgrade